# How do you reference a C++ dynamic Android library in Xamarin VS2015?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a Xamarin project `MyApp` within VS2015. This ends up creating a bunch of projects including `MyApp.Droid` for Android. I can build and deploy this project just fine on my Android device.

Next, I created a shared C++ Dynamic Shared Library (Android) project `MyShared`. When I try to add this project as a reference in `MyApp.Droid`, it reports an error that only .dll or .exe file types can be added as a reference and not .so types.

Wondering if there is a different way to add a native library project as a dependency. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`Xamarin.Android` supports the use of native libraries via the standard *PInvoke* mechanism.

You will need to define the DllImport C# attributes/signatures, there are various tools such as SWIG, PInvoker Visual Studio Addin, Mono's CppSharp, etc.. that can assist in this step.

(Personally I use Mono's CppSharp, but it might be overkill depending upon the number of classes/methods/functions there are within your C++ library.)

- [Mono Interop with Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/)
- [Xamarin.Android : Using Native Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/)

> To interop with native libraries in your Xamarin.Android project, all you need to do is create a DllImport function declaration for the existing code to invoke, and the runtime will handle the rest. Set the EntryPoint to specify the exact function to be called in the native code.

- [Build and Debug C++ Libraries in Xamarin.Android Apps with Visual Studio 2015](https://blog.xamarin.com/build-and-debug-c-libraries-in-xamarin-android-apps-with-visual-studio-2015/)